# Search a string followed by an end of line

Tags: emacs

In `Emacs`, I use `Ctrl+s` to go through a string in a text.

Now, I am interested in a string `abc`, only when it is in the end of a line. We can say alternatively, a string `abc` which follows by an end of line.

Does anyone know how can I search that in `Emacs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-M-s</kbd> `abc$`

`C-M-s` calls `isearch-forward-regexp`

If you've already typed <kbd>C-s</kbd> `abc` before realising you need a regexp search, just type <kbd>M-r</kbd> and isearch will switch to using regexps.

Alternatively, you could (in the majority of cases) use:
<kbd>C-s</kbd> `abc` <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd>

As <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> is the way to type a newline character into the search pattern (being a `quoted-insert` of `C-j`).

Comment: and, as I am sure you intended to write, `$` in an Emacs regex matches an end of line.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning too is the difference between the two search patterns: `C-s abc C-q C-j` matches also the newline character, whereas `C-M-s abc$` does not.